# Searching for 8-bit aligned string in a 9-bit architecture

Tags: c, string, bit-manipulation

I need to search for a 8-bit aligned bit string "00 00 01" (hex) in a character stream. On a typical architecture, I would do it as such:

```
char *find(char *first, char *last)
{
    char pattern[] = {0, 0, 1};
    char *p;

    for (p = first; last - p >= sizeof(pattern); ++p) {
        if (!memcmp(p, pattern, sizeof(pattern))
            return p;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, I don't know how I would implement this function (with good performance) if char was not 8-bits.

Comment: So are you saying that you still have 8 bit bytes available, but the content of one "spills over" into the next by 1 bit? So after 9 bytes (72 bits, 8 long-bytes), you're back in alignment for the next byte?

Comment: (Mostly) gone, but not forgotten: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/36-bit . One question though: what is the bit order? In other words, to get the first group of 8 bits from the first 9-bit 'byte', should I get the 8 most significant bits, or the 8 least significant bits?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. On my 9-bit architecture, CHAR_BIT = 9. The first argument to find() can be assumed to be aligned on a 8-bit boundary. I need to find the bit string at a bit offset that is a multiple of 8-bits. Bit ordering is high to low. If a 9-bit char pointer points to a 8-bit aligned character, then it contains that character in its most significant 8 bits and then the top bit of the next 8-bit character in its low bit.

Comment: What is the max bit length of `pattern`.  Unbounded?, 24/27 bits?

Comment: Do you need to search for that specific string (23 zero bits followed by 1 set bit)?

Comment: There is a bounded length of pattern, which is a multiple of 8 bits. Right now, I need to look for this pattern, but there are other patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task is quite interesting one, so I'm coming with another option. It doesn't require to convert your stream bits into chars, instead we could use following pattern.

Since your bit values shall have 8 bit alignment, possible char index / it's start bit options are:

```
char 0, bit 0 (its starting bit index)
char 0, bit 8
char 1, bit 7
char 2, bit 6
char 3, bit 5
char 4, bit 4
char 5, bit 3
char 6, bit 2
char 7, bit 1
```

for the char 8, the starting bit would be 0, so it same as 1st item (char 0, bit 0)

Now except first position, remaining 8 possibilities are easy to verify by single expression:

The pseudo code:

```
int   pattern = 0x000001L;
int   mask = ~pattern;
int   char_idx = 0;

while (first <= last-2)   // need to compare 3 chars
{
    int   value = *((int*)first)); // this will actually access 4 chars, if stream has no 0 terminator, it will produce exception

    // special [char 0, bit 0] case
    if ( !char_idx && (value & mask) == pattern )
    {
        // match! do something with *first
    }

    if ( ((value >> (8 - char_idx)) & mask) == pattern ) 
    {
        // match! do something with *first
    }

    if ( ++char_idx == 9 )
       char_idx = 0;

    first++;
}
```

NOTE: if your int is not 36 bit, you can do char-by-char comparision

Comment: I will accept this answer because of the elegant way it handles alignment and how it can be applied to longer patterns. However, your unconventional bit numbering scheme confused me for a moment.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to explain it :) Also added some comments

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work under the following conditions:

- `long` is 36 bits (4 bytes of 9 bits each)
- big-endian architecture; the most siginificant bits of a `long` value are stored at the lowest address
- `long *` can point to any address, not necessarily a multiple of four; in other words, no word or dword alignment
- the pattern we are searching for is 24 bits (can be adjusted, but absolute maximum for this approach is 28 bits)

The function does not return a `char *` since that doesn't say much about the actual bit position. Instead, it returns the number of 8-bit groups that precede the match, or -1 if no match.

```
long find(char *first, char *last)
{
    long pattern = 0x000001L;      // the bit string we are searching for
    long bitmask = -0x1000L;       // initial mask: 24 ones followed by 12 zeroes
    long maxcount = ((last - first) * 9 - 24) / 8;    // 24 = pattern size (bits)
    long count;                    // counts the 8-bit groups
    char *slider = first;          // follows the 9-bit bytes
    for (count = 0; count <= maxcount; count++) {
        long actual = (*(long *)slider & bitmask);
        long expect = (bitmask & -bitmask) * pattern;
        if (actual == expect) return count;

        if (bitmask & 0xFF) {    // less than 8 zeroes on the right-hand side
            slider++;
            bitmask <<= 1;       // shift 9 bits to left, then 8 bits to right
        }
        else {
            bitmask >>= 8;       // shift 8 bits to the right, only
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I have no idea how to test this, so it's on an 'as is' basis.

The function uses a `bitmask` with exactly 24 ones. The bits are continuously shifted 8 positions to the right. If a '1' threatens to be shifted out, then the memory pointer `slider` is incremented and the `bitmask` is adjusted accordingly.

`slider` is defined as `char *`, and cast to `long *` when being dereferenced, retrieving four 9-bit bytes in one go. If I would define `slider` as `long *`, then `slider++` would proceed the pointer by 4 bytes instead of one.

Here's an example to explain this obscure expression: `(bitmask & -bitmask) * pattern`

- 000011111111111111111111111100000000 = `bitmask`
- 111100000000000000000000000100000000 = `-bitmask`
- 000000000000000000000000000100000000 = `(bitmask & -bitmask)`
- 0000pppppppppppppppppppppppp00000000 = `(bitmask & -bitmask) * pattern`

As you can see, it aligns `pattern` (the 24 bits `pppppppppppppppppppppppp`) with the `bitmask`.

Please let me know how this works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

What the hell is that, the 9-bit architecture? :) So the 'char' type is also 9 bit? :)

The quick and dirty way would be to convert char stream into bit-to-char representation, in other words every char representing a bit. Then just search for substring of "000001", with the alignment of 8 chars (memcmp at first[0], then memcp at first[8] etc)... Surely it is possible to do it in a 'binary'/right way, but depending on how long the stream is this could be the 'good performance' way...